# How to attach vintage door handles properly

Tags: doors

I live in an old building with old brass door handles, which the previous owner attached with screws or nails. Therefore the handles are very wobbly and I would like to attach them properly.

My question is how where these door handles originally attached?

I've seen in other old buildings, those kind of door handles being attached with a metal pin that seemed to be hit through with a hammer. If that's the case, what is this hardware called and where can it be obtained?

[image: door handle]
[image: door handle detail]

Comment: Full disclosure: I rejected the proposed edit. "Fixate" is an archaic usage; "attach" is more common, but I don't think anyone misunderstands the intent here. I'm invoking the "be nice" clause and not changing the OPs words.

Comment: "Fixate" in modern English is to focus on intently, possibly to the exclusion of all else. While most native English speakers would understand the meaning, it is a _very_ awkward usage. I prefer to make corrections in the hopes that others will learn to speak more native-sounding English. I wouldn't object to someone nicely correcting my attempts at <not-English>.

Comment: To address the current discussion, I propose "affixed" as a near substitute (or simply "fixed" to use a lovely classic form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure the diameter of the holes in the handle and shaft. Dress and repair as necessary.

Make or purchase new pins. Some “pins” are just that and held in place by friction, others may have had threads and the pins were long thin screws - often with just a short thread at the head end.

Comment: The "shaft" appears to simply have a pinned notch for handle retention, not a hole.  I suspect the OP's problem is that the tip of the shaft is a loose fit in the socket of the handle, allowing it to wobble even though pinned.  I'd suggest trying to fill some of the space in the socket with something like JB Weld before pinning the handle, to remove the "space" left.  OP can wrap the shaft with something like saran wrap, if concerned about future removal.

Comment: Good point, @Huesmann. If there's wear, especially from years of being attached loosely, then the joint may just be sloppy and needs to be tightened up. It might be better to put a little JB Weld on the shaft, allowing it to set, then file it down to fit in the handle again. Getting it properly shaped once in the hole of handle might be darn near impossible.

Comment: The pins might be called "pins" if solid or "roll pins" if made from a sheet of metal that is rolled into a cylinder. Either type should work fine for this. There are probably other types of pins I can't think of at the moment.

Comment: @FreeMan I still think it's better to put the JB Weld on wet and let it squish to fill the space.  Filing and reinserting just seems like it'd be difficult to get just right.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I managed to find cylindrical pins, which fit very tightly, having to hammer them through.